# cannot pass params from servlet to jsp (jstl)

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

i'm trying to pass a `List<String[]>` object to my jsp page and handle it with jstl.

my servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("rows", entries);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
${rows}
<c:forEach items="${rows}" var="row">
   <tr>
      <c:forEach items="${row}" var="field">
         <td>${field}</td>
      </c:forEach>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

the params are not recognized - meaning they are printed as `${rows}` and `${field}`

the funny thing is that when i do the same using this way (which i understand is bad practice):

```
<% 
List<String[]> entries = (List<String[]>) request.getAttribute("rows"); 
for...
%>
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *meaning they are printed as ${rows} and ${field}*

So, EL expressions are not evaluated? That can happen when there's a version incompatibility between the JSTL version used, the servletcontainer version used and the webapp's `web.xml` version.

First you need to figure which Servlet API version is max supported by the target servletcontainer. Then you can determine which JSTL version you actually need and which version the `web.xml` should be declared to.

Imagine that you're using Tomcat 7, which is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, then you should be using at least JSTL 1.2 and the `web.xml` should be declared conform Servlet 3.0. Or if you're using Tomcat 6, which is a Servlet 2.5 compatible container, then you should be using at least JSTL 1.1 and the `web.xml` should be declared conform Servlet 2.5.

A more rare cause, but not uncommon among beginners, is that webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` is incorrectly been cluttered with servletcontainer-specific JAR files such as `el-api.jar` and so on, which would only conflict the EL installation provided by the target servletcontainer itself.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) - contains version/installation details, download links and web.xml examples.